# Архитектура и проектирование. Различие в смысле слов

Tags: значение-слов

Я начинающий software engineer, и мне очень сложно понять что значат слова *архитектура* и *проектирование*, в чем их взаимосвязь? Пожалуйста, поясните простыми словами на примере общего определения этих слов.

Comment: Мне кажется, этот вопрос лучше задать не на сайте про русский язык, а на сайте кодеров. Мы можем вам объяснить, в чём разница с точки зрения лингвистики, но не в чём разница с точки зрения профессионального кодинга.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он не входит в компетенцию нашего сообщества.

Comment: Я и хочу узнать с точки зрения лингвистики

Comment: Я просил терминологию и объяснения в coding? Я просил общее понятие двух этих слов

Comment: С какой целью с порога представляться по профессиональному признаку, если цель обращения обычная — в пределах школы? Одну часть клоунады @Артём Луговой убрал, уберите и другую и поясните, в чём трудность.